# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=505),

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

1.This is my entity class.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Leads {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String source;
    private String mobile;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

2. This is my  controller layer

```
package com.mento1.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.mento1.entities.Leads;
import com.mento1.service.LeadsService;


@Controller
public class LeadsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private LeadsService leadService;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/leads")
    public String showLeadsPage() {
        return "saveLeads";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/saveLead")
    public String saveLead(@ModelAttribute("lead")Leads lead, ModelMap modelMap) {
        leadService.saveLead(lead);
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "Lead is saved");
        return "saveLeads";
    }
}
```

3.This is my view layer

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>lead</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create new leads</h2>
    <form action="saveLead" method="post">
    <pre>
        first name <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
        last name  <input type="text" name= "lastName"/>
        email      <input type="text" name="email" />
        source     <select name="source">
                 <option value="News Paper">News Paper</option>
                 <option value="TV Commercial">TV Commercial</option>
                 <option value="Online">Online</option>
                 <option value="radio">radio</option>
            </select>
            
        mobile     <input type="text" name="mobile" />
                   <input type="Submit" value="save" />
        </pre>          
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

4. application properties file- here I have configure my data base

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mentoDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Subrat02

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
```

5. This is my Repository layer extended jpa repository

```
package com.mento1.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mento1.entities.Leads;



public interface LeadsRepository extends JpaRepository<Leads, Long> {

}
```

6.This is my service layer interface

```
package com.mento1.service;

import com.mento1.entities.Leads;

public interface LeadsService {

    
        public void saveLead(Leads lead);
}
```

7. This is my service layer class.

```
package com.mento1.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mento1.entities.Leads;
import com.mento1.repositories.LeadsRepository;


@Service
public class LeadsServiceImpl implements LeadsService {

    @Autowired
    private LeadsRepository leadRepo;
    
    @Override
    public void saveLead(Leads lead) {
        leadRepo.save(lead);

    }

}
```

8. Error Coming:-

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Feb 13 09:24:29 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=505)

The problem is I am not able to save the data in the data base.

Comment: Which URL is not found?

Comment: You are trying to access through POST method by form but you have not mentioned it in controller by default controller takes it as GET.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your codes. I think your problem is related to entity class. You don't have got constructor methods in Leads class. You must be add this methods with parameter and non-parameter. This really a huge problem.
And you haven't got all annotations. I recommend to use"Lombok" dependencies for constructor and annotations. You don't need to write getter/setter or constructor methods if you use Lombok.
Then you add Lombok to dependencies and set up it. (You can search to how install lombok to spring-boot project). You just should add some annotations to your entity.
I write my entity class as an example.

```
package datum....entities.concretes;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "column_table")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ColumnTable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "clmn_id")
public int clmnId;

@Column(name = "database_id")
public int databaseId;

@Column(name = "schema_id")
public int schemaId;

@Column(name = "table_id")
public int tableId;

@Column(name = "column_id")
public int columnId;

@Column(name = "column_name")
public String columnName;

@Column(name = "type_name")
public String typeName;

@Column(name = "max_len")
public int maxLen;

@Column(name = "prec")
public int prec;

@Column(name = "nullable")
public int nullable;

@Column(name = "columnDescription")
public String columnDescription;

@Column(name = "sample_name")
public String sampleName;
}
```